# Combining wp_list_authors with get_user_meta

Tags: user-meta, list-authors

i am using the wp_list_authors function as the following:

```
<?php wp_list_authors( array(
'show_fullname' => 'true',
'orderby'       => 'display_name',
'order'         => 'ASC'
)) ?>
```

However this shows the authors by **firstname + lastname** I want to switch that so it shows the users **lastname + firstname**.

I cant figure out how can i use the **get_user_meta** in the function.

It is possible or should I use something else than wp_list_authors?

Comment: Could you include the rest of the code? how are you outputing the name? include the foreach or for loop that you used.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast `wp_list_authors()` does the outputting.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast as Jacob mentiones wp_list_authors() does the outputting.

Comment: Was to quick to comment, my mistake. You are right, never used the function before so I assumed it return a array, after reading the documentation I see that it outputs by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not supported by `wp_list_authors()`. To output them the way you want you will need to use `get_users()` and display them yourself.

```
$authors = get_users(
    array(
        'orderby' => 'display_name',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    )
);

foreach ( $authors as $author ) {
    echo esc_html( $author->last_name . ' ' . $author->first_name );
}
```

You can wrap the output in elements as needed, and pass `$author->ID` to `get_user_meta()` if you need any metadata. You can get a link to the author archive using [`get_author_posts_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/).

Comment: @Buttered_Toast yeah I think he meant that because it works with $authors = get_users

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I did, yes. Fixed.